# ray sensor not publishing points properly

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to visualise velodyne hdl 32 in rviz and the point cloud created by this sensor in rviz, but the output point cloud is not coming realistic, as i've seen it should come like this
[image: image,]

but i am visualising the point cloud in rviz like [image: this]:

First i though that this kind of output is coming because angular velocity of velodyne is less but even after i made it rotate faster, same type of output point cloud comes, so can anyone explain me what is this happening. I am using a ray sensor as laser source for velodyne.

```
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/laser</robotNamespace>
      <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
<gazebo reference="top">
  <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
    <pose>0 0 0.09 1.5708 0 -1.5708</pose>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
    <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    <ray>
     <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.1</stddev>
     </noise>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>32</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-0.53529248</min_angle>
          <max_angle>0.18622663

</max_angle>
        </horizontal>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.05</min>
        <max>70</max>
        <resolution>0.02</resolution>
      </range>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="hokuyo_node" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so"> <-- or libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser-->
      <topicName>/myrobot1/laser/scan</topicName>
      <frameName>base</frameName>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>

</gazebo>
```

the ray sensors in gazebo is seen like:
[image: image description]
I'm using ros indigo with gazebo 7.4. i also tired gpy_ray sensor and block_laser but they didn't worked.
My velodyne xacro file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="laser" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
<xacro:include filename="$(find myrobot1_description)/urdf/laser.gazebo" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find myrobot1_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />

  <link name="base">

    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.078335"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://myrobot1_description/meshes/velodyne_base.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.078335"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://myrobot1_description/meshes/velodyne_base.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.078335"/>
      <mass value="0.5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.000090623" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.000090623" iyz="0.0" izz="0.000091036"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <link name="top">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://myrobot1_description/meshes/velodyne_top.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://myrobot1_description/meshes/velodyne_top.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.000090623" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.000090623" iyz="0.0" izz="0.000091036"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.077"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-10000000000000000" upper="10000000000000000" velocity="0.5"/>
    <parent link="base"/>
    <child link="top"/>
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

</robot>
```

I also succesfully used block_lase sensor and plugin but still i got the same type of visualization in rviz but with different display type topic"pointcloud" instead of laser display in rviz. Here the output came little realistic but it came only in one direction not in all 360 degree .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251473/ray-sensor-not-publishing-points-properly/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-01-09**:
Are you using the [gazebo velodyne plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i1)?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-01-09**:
I have modified that same sdf file of velodyne sensor to xacro format so i can launch it from ros node and than visualize it in rviz and than control its velocity from ros topic. I have added `gazebo_ros_laser` plugin below the ray sensor element in urdf.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-01-10**:
I am still confused. You are using gazebo, and not data from a real device? You are using rviz to see the result?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-01-10**:
Yes i am trying to simulate a velodyne hdl_32 laser sensor in gazebo and than by using ray sensor and gazebo_ros_gpu plugin i am subscring the point clouds published by it inside the rviz for visualization how is it working. i also used gpu_ray_plugin but it also shows same output points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok this is working like a charm, someone may find it useful so i put it here, in rviz the points looks beautiful like from real sensor like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkYRBFR3iqc), at that time velodyne was not rotating but right now it is, but still here the main plugin code which u can use in in ur urdf or xacro file and visualize block_laser in rviz:

```
  <gazebo reference="top">
    <sensor name="sonar" type="ray">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>12</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
            <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>2</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.001</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.05</min>
          <max>50.0</max>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="sonar_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_block_laser.so">
        <gaussianNoise>0.00</gaussianNoise>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>/output_point_cloud</topicName>
        <frameName>sonar_ring</frameName>
      </plugin>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>100.0</update_rate>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

and yes, anyone can play with the parameters in the sensor element to make it more better.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0